# no see guarda el select multiple

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, array

Buen día a todos, tengo un select multiple se envia por json a php el cual proceso la información se guardan todos los campos menos el select multiple he buscado por todos lados pero no entiendo que mismo hacer para que se almacene, agradeceria su ayuda.

```
$id_usuario         = trim($_POST['id_usuario']);
    $activo_user        = $_POST['activoUser'];
    $id_empresa         = $_POST['empresa'];
    $id_sucursal        = $_POST['newUserSuc'];
    $nombres            = $_POST['nombre'];
    $apellidos          = $_POST['apellido'];
    $nombre_usuario     = $_POST['userLogin'];
    $email              = $_POST['emailUser'];
    $cargo_usuario      = $_POST['cargo'];
    $id_rol_usuario     = $_POST['nivel'];
    $dni_user           = $_POST['cedula'];
    $fecha_nac          = $_POST['fechaNac'];
    $e_civil            = $_POST['eCivil'];
    $email_adicional    = $_POST['emailAddic'];
    $telefono           = $_POST['telfUser'];
    $notas_info         = $_POST['notasUser'];
    $fecha_reg          = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $con = Conectar();
    $SQL = "UPDATE `usuarios` SET `id_empresa` = '$id_empresa', `id_sucursal` = '".$id_sucursal."', `nombres` = '$nombres', `apellidos` = '$apellidos', `cedula` = '$dni_user', `nombre_usuario` = '$nombre_usuario', `email` = '$email', `fecha_nac` = '$fecha_nac', `e_civil` = '$e_civil', `email_adicional` = '$email_adicional', `notas_info` = '$notas_info', `fecha_reg` = '$fecha_reg', `cargo_usuario` = '$cargo_usuario', `id_rol_usuario` = '$id_rol_usuario', `telefono` = '$telefono', `cta_activa` = '$activo_user', `activo` = '1' WHERE `usuarios`.`id_usuarios` = '$id_usuario'";
    $stmt = $con->prepare($SQL);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
```

La respuesta llega al server por la variable $id_sucursal llega asi como array pero no se almacena en mysql sale este error Warning:  Array to string conversion in c...

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 4
)
```

Comment: Pero el campo id_sucursal de que tipo es?  cuando el usuario pertenece a varias sucursales como quieres que se guarde el dato?  Por ejemplo, id_sucursal="3,4"?  Si es así utiliza por ejemplo `id_sucursal = '".implode(',',$id_sucursal)."'` en la consulta.

Comment: Es de tipo array porque lo defini $newUserSuc = [] y como es array no se quiere cuardar en la base de datos ahora voy a poner el impode a ver que pasa, gracias masterguru aun no aprendo como etiquetarte para que salga que te repondi a ti

Comment: Ya use el implode pero no sigue el mismo error ;-( <b>Warning</b>:  Array to string conversion in <b>C:\xampp2022\htdocs\gestion2022\api\add_user.php</b> on line <b>26</b> en esa linea esta es el UPDATE con el implode

Comment: eso del implode va en la linea del UPDATE... si lo has hecho asi y sigue dando el error es porque alguna otra variable tambien debe ser un array. Revisa el formulario que no tengas alguna con el `name="variable[]"` (acabado en corchetes, pues entonces se recibiria por POST como array tambien)

Comment: @masterguru efectivamente si tengo otra array y faltaba lo mismo al fin de amo gracias hermano :-)

Comment: @masterguru Funcion a la perfeccttion el asunto es que  si quiero leer el campo para una posible actualizacion imagino que se debu usar el explode, pero como lo uso en el SELECT *, id_sucursales FROM usuario?

Comment: Prueba con [FIND_IN_SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)... aqui encontraras un buen ejemplo: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-find_in_set/

Comment: Fíjate que tambien hablan de [IN](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_in.asp) que quizás te guste más para lo que pretendes

Comment: @masterguru No funciono usando el FIND IN SET me genera un error <b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'FIND_IN_SET' in C...

Comment: Como bien dice @padaleiana, deberias hacer una nueva pregunta con eso, sino vamos a llenar los comentarios de nuevas cosas, que aunque esten relacionadas con la pregunta inicial, surgen despues de aplicar su solución.  En la nueva pregunta especifica bien la consulta que haces, pues no te dice que la función no exista, sino que esta mal escrita... ¿ te has mirado bien los enlaces con los ejemplos que te he puesto antes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

funciono pero el detalle que tengo ahora es que al guardar los valor con el implode se guardaron 1,2,8 etc ahora como los hago otravez como eran al comienzo para devolverlos a una actualización al select multiple ya que el select mutiple no se aunto selecciona dichos campos a modificar.

Comment: Si algo en los comentarios te funcionó, ponlo como respuesta (en base a [answer]) y [acéptala](/help/accepted-answer) cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo. Si esto es una nueva pregunta, debes formularla como otra pregunta. Recuerda que [es.so] no tiene el formato de hilos, ni es un foro.

Comment: @padaleiana Gracias por el detalle y la informacion